# AMPL IDE usage issue

Tags: ide, ampl

I want to use AMPL student version. 
also I apply its IDE for mathematical modelling, but when I open it, it pop-up a box showing the following message.

`A valid AMPL license file could not be found for this machine.
For assistance, copy this entire message and send it to licensing@ampl.com.
Details:
License file ampl.lic not found anywhere in $PATH.`

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMPL IDE distribution available for download from http://www.ampl.com/IDE/ includes a full version of ampl which requires a license. To use the student version, you need to replace the ampl and solver binaries in the `amplide/ampl` directory with their student versions available [here](http://ampl.com/netlib/ampl/student/index.html).

Alternatively, you can download a demo version of the IDE from one of the following locations:

- Linux: http://ampl.com/dl/demo/amplide-demo-linux32.tar.gz
- OS X: http://ampl.com/dl/demo/amplide-demo-macosx.tar.gz
- Windows: http://ampl.com/dl/demo/amplide-demo-mswin.zip

Answer (score 1):

Simply place the [amplide](http://www.ampl.com/IDE/) folder inside the [amplcml](http://www.ampl.com/NEW/TABLES/amplcml.zip) folder (which is the free student version of AMPL).

[image]